# Queuing of Request taking around 1-3 sec delay in chrome browser for angular2 and RX js

Tags: angular, performance, google-chrome, browser, rxjs

I am currently working in angular-2 project and using RX js. During performance analysis get some issue for HTTP calls,Below is the details about the problem.

There is 1-3 sec delay for queuing the two subsequent request.
below is the screen shot for the same can anyone help me out why this delay occurs or is it a normal behavior.
[first call for textMaskcore.js](https://i.stack.imgur.com/FwyX0.png)

the first request for the above textMaskCore.js file queued in 1.29s 
but the subsequent call for defaultCCMAFamilyMap.json queued in 3.74s
why there is a huge difference between the queuing time though both the files are loading from browser cache and i observed the first call is in pending state for a long time.
below is the screen shot for the second request.[call for defaultccma.json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/WcUTS.png)

below is the screen shot for the same that both the files loaded from cache
[files loaded from cache](https://i.stack.imgur.com/fgA7Q.png)

Thanks in advance

Comment: Hey, having the same problem 3y later, have you found a solution?